# In-line View Definitions Couch Db Ektorp

Tags: java, spring, nosql, couchdb, ektorp

I use Couch DB with Ektorp at Spring 3. I read the document and have tried to implement examples. I am so new to these technologies. This is the point where I didn't understand:

```
@View( name = "all", map = "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'Sofa' ) emit( null, doc._id )}")
public class SofaRepository extends CouchDbRepositorySupport<Sofa> {

    @View( name = "avg_sofa_size", map = "function(doc) {...}", reduce = "function(doc) {...}")
    public int getAverageSofaSize() {
        ViewResult r = db.queryView(createQuery("avg_sofa_size"));
        return r.getRows().get(0).getValueAsInt();
    }

}
```

How does that wievs work and how to define them, what happens at that lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CouchDbRepositorySupport` out of the box provides the following methods to the SofaRepository:

```java
public void add(Sofa entity);
public void update(Sofa entity);
public void remove(Sofa entity);
public Sofa get(String id);
public Sofa get(String id, String rev);
public List<T> getAll();
public boolean contains(String docId);
```

By having this inline view annotation for `CouchDbRepositorySupport`:

```java
@View( name = "all", map = "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'Sofa' ) emit( null, doc._id )}")
```

You redefine the return from a `getAll()` method.

You also adding *another* method `getAverageSofaSize()` to your repository, with inline View:

```java
@View( name = "avg_sofa_size", map = "function(doc) {...}", reduce = "function(doc) {...}")
```

which explicitly provides a `query` that `db.queryView(createQuery("avg_sofa_size"));` undersntad. `db` here is a [CouchDbConnector](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp/blob/master/org.ektorp/src/main/java/org/ektorp/CouchDbConnector.java) that is able to create, delete, purge, find, etc..

Take a look at more documentation about [defining in line Views](http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d0e753)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation I got it. Can you explain more how that view functions works i.e. emit method?

Comment: Sure. `emit` is an equivalent of `map` in map/reduce, where it just maps out all the values/ranges/data to _potentially_ be reduced later on. In this [first function] example, it `emit`s ( think about it as `returns` ) all the documents with a type=='Sofa'. You can read about it more in [CouchDB docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Map_Functions)